# Can’t Find A Way To Configure Any TinyMCE Image Upload Plugin in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce, codeigniter-2, image-uploading

I’m relatively new to CI but I am enjoying it alot.

I have built a rather robust form that uses TinyMCE to fix the markup. One of my needs is to have images be uploaded rather than hotlinked.

I have attempted to run multiple different TinyMCE Upload plugins but all seem to have path configuration issues or Apache blocks whathaveyou.

When reading the CI documentation I seem to remember something about uploading but I don’t really follow it.

Is there something I’m not doing? Perhaps something with Routes or .htaccess? Is there a recommended TinyMCE upload method with CI?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the folder in which you are uploading the image should be placed at "public_html"
not in any sub-directories. i.e the image upload folder should be in the parent folder

Comment: actually it can be set anywhere on filesystem, as long as user privileges are set right.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own JQuery/Angular/Whatever event on upload button click and send an Ajax call to your server with data. You can use JQuery to pull data from inputs and send them to the form processing controller like illustrated [here](https://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/).

Suppose this is your input:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" required />
```

Your js will contain  a JQuery trigger and a separate Jquery function to make the Ajax call as below.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  toolbar: 'mybutton',
  menubar: false,
  setup: function (editor) {
  editor.addButton('mybutton', {
  text: 'My button',
  icon: false,
  onclick: function () {
   //Trigger Submit event on input
   $("#uploadimage").trigger('submit');
  }
});
  },
     content_css: [
      '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
       '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
       ]
});

  //Triggered on submit
$("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#message").empty();
$('#loading').show();
$.ajax({
url: "ajax_php_file.php", // Url to which the request is send
type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
{
$('#loading').hide();
$("#message").html(data);
}
});
}));
```

Use CI form upload library to create a controller that can handle the uploaded file. Frankly I prefer Froala over TinyMCE because it has all these nifty little things figured out beforehand and probably has more features and can be skinned. Whatever floats your goat man. Let me know if this worked out. I just prepped this code on the spot and its pretty lazy. You could move the form handling function in your TinyMCE init. Cheers!